# How to find an element by id that is a child of either of two classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with an id that sometimes appears in `<body class="boxes new">`, sometimes in `<body class="boxes create">` and sometime in a `<body>` with different classes. Here is how I find it for the first case:

```
$('body.boxes.new #submit_box')
```

Can I find it with one line of jQuery for classes `new` and `create` instead of two lines like below?

```
$('body.boxes.new #submit_box').doSomething()
$('body.boxes.create #submit_box').doSomething()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine the selectors with a comma, `,`:

```
$('body.boxes.create #submit_box, body.boxes.new #submit_box').doSomething();
```

You could also use the [`.find()` method](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$('body.boxes.create, body.boxes.new').find('#submit_box').doSomething()
```

or use a [context selector](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1):

```
$('#submit_box', 'body.boxes.create, body.boxes.new').doSomething()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)**.

> Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.

```
 $('body.boxes.new #submit_box,body.boxes.create #submit_box').doSomething()
```

or

```
 $('body.boxes.new,body.boxes.create').find('#submit_box').doSomething()
```

Comment: I don't have elements with the same ID. It's just the same jQuery code executed for different html files, each with unique `submit_box` id.

Comment: in that case you should simply use `$("#submit_box")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370255/how-to-find-element-by-id-if-it-has-either-of-two-classes#comment46921775_29370307

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the id is that you target it directly. Why wouldn't `$("#submit_box")` work?

Comment: It seems like the OP doesn't want to target it *unless* it is a child of a specific class. So, this answer is actually wrong.

Comment: Because the same button is in a create and edit view, and I want to assign a click event only in create/new view. Exactly like @JoshCrozier said.